# How do dollar and number sign together work in perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, operators

Today I have encountered a problem that required me to determine the maximum index of an array in perl. I used to do it this way:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3);
print $array[@array - 1];
```

But today I have stumbled upon this code:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3);
print $array[$#array];
```

I couldn't find anything on that matter in the docs. What exactly is that `$#` construct? Is that an operator? And how does it work, is it faster than the first piece of code? Does it always return the maximum array index? Is it deprecated or not?

I know that's a lot of questions, but they all can be summed up by one, and that's what I really want to know: **How does it work?**

Comment: `$#array` will tell you the number of the last index, but if you just want to get the last item (and you don't care about its actual index) it's much easier to use `$array[-1]`

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997042/where-is-the-documentation-for

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is documented in [perldoc perldata, section "Scalar Values"](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perldata#Scalar_values). In short, `$#array` is the last index of `@array`. As for how it works — it's sort of like an operator, but only as much as `$` and `@` are operators. Think of it as special syntax. The last index of an array just happens to "have a name". It's a variable that you can read from and assign to.

Answer (score 8):

The use is mentioned in first example in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html). It denotes index of last item in the array.

Btw, you can also use

```
$array[-1]
```

to get last item.

Answer (score 3):

That gives you the last index. It's documented in perldata - http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html